# unity slide sphere on a slope without rotating

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, physics, gravity

I have a ramp and I move a sphere with arrows. I have unity's gravity and I want the rigid body of sphere to slide when it is stoped at the top of the ramp but without rotating it's body. The problem is if I Freeze rotation on x axis, it won't slide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new [Physical Material](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) and set both dynamic and static friction to 0. Then drag it to  the sphere and maybe also to the ramp.

Test with both rotation constrained and not.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use physics materials like ice and freeze rotations.

See info about materials [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html). "Like ice" means than you need set frictions to zero.

Comment: Arh, you're 14 seconds earlier.

Comment: @ChanibaL, almost at the same time :D